# Matlab - Roots of polynomial with varying coefficients

Tags: matlab, solver, polynomials

Suppose `p=[3,2,1]`. Then, `roots(p)` gives the roots of `3x^2+2x+1`.

What if the coefficients of a polynomial depend on a coefficient `a`? Like a polynomial `3x^2+2x+a`. If I define `p = @(a) [3,2,a]` then `roots(p)` doesn't work. The error is

```
Undefined function 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
```

Is there a way of adjusting the `roots` function or do I have to retreat to `fsolve` to find the roots of a polynomial with varying coefficients?

Comment: what version of Matlab do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `a` as a symbolic variable as follows:

```
syms a
```

Then

```
p = [3,2,a]
roots(p)
```

should work. I am using R2019b.

For more complex examples, if you know anything about the variable `a` (e.g. `a` is a real), you should let the `roots()` function know by defining the variable as a real:

```
syms a real
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine! I'm using R2019a.